# hide the reCAPTCHA Enterprise badge

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

We have reviewed the documentation regarding the possibility of hiding the reCAPTCHA Enterprise badge (https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/faq#id_like_to_hide_the_badge_what_is_allowed) and have some specific questions about scenarios not clearly outlined in the documentation. We would like to know if it is permissible to adopt one of the following three approaches:

1. **Completely hiding the badge without any disclosur**e: We would like to understand if it is allowed to remove the reCAPTCHA Enterprise badge entirely from our site without including any text indicating its use.
2. **Inclusion of the required disclosure in our site's general policy**: Is it acceptable to include the statement that we use reCAPTCHA Enterprise to protect our site and that "Google's Terms of Service and Privacy Policy apply" within the general policy of the site, which is already referenced in the form? For example, in each form, we would refer to our own policy, and within the extended text of that policy, we would insert the required disclosure.
3. **Hiding the badge via CSS and displaying it only when the user interacts with the form**: Can we hide the badge using CSS and make it visible only at the moment when the user starts interacting with the form?

We aim to comply with the guidelines while also maintaining the aesthetics and user experience of our site.

We have attempted to hide it using CSS, but we want validation of the solution.

Comment: No, as per google terms you can only hide the badge and google's official terms and conditions should be disgustingly visible to the users while interacting with your site. You have to keep them separately from the policies of your website. you can try the third method you mentioned however you need to take care that all these policies and guidelines should be visible wherever you are using reCaptcha.